# How to Implement Ajax Pagination in Custom module

Tags: ajax, magento2.2.2, pagination

Phtml File

```
 $('.pagination a').on('click', function() {
       var pagNo = $('a').val();

          $("#data-loader").css("background", "url("+ajaxloader+") no-repeat");
           $("#data-loader").addClass('data-loader'); 

         $.ajax({
                            method: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>",
                            data: { PagNo: PagNo}
                    }).done(function( res ) {

                        //alert(res.Data);
                        //capt2();
                          $("#data-loader").removeClass('data-loader');  
                        $('#ajax').html('');
                         $('#ajax').html(res.Data);
                         capt2();
                            if(res.error === false){

                               // alert(res.error);


                            }
                            else{
                                // alert(res.message);
                            }                           
                   });
    })

  <div class="pagination">
  <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="active">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <a href="#">5</a>
  <a href="#">6</a>
  <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
  </div>
```

Block File

```
public function getProductPageAjax($product_id, $type, $arrow, $pagNo)
{

    $collection = $this->_Model->getCollection()
                                    ->joinProductAttachmentTable()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product_id)
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status', 1)
                                    ->joinTopicTable()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('topic_table.identifier', 'product');

    $this->setCollection($collection);


    $collection->setLimit(1)->setShowPerPage(false)->setCurPage($pagNo)
    ->setShowAmounts(false)
    ->setCollection($this->getCollection());
    $collection = $this->getCollection()->load();

    return $collection;
 }
```

Controller File

```
public function execute()
{
     $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();

         $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

   // $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    $faqsHelper = $this->_objectManager->get('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');


    $values[] = $params['value'];
    $values[] = $params['proid'];
    $values[] = $params['sortbyarrow'];
    $values[] = $params['PagNo'];



    $data= $this->_view->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock("Vendor\Module\Block\Product\MyBlock")
                 ->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::myphtml.phtml")
                 ->setData('sort_type', $values)
                 ->toHtml();


     return  $resultJson->setData([
            'Data' => $data,

       ]);


    //return $resultPage;
}
```

I don't know how to implement it, please guide me to implement it.

Comment: Exactly what problem you are facing?

Comment: it just doesn't work at all.

Comment: Did you created the **`route.xml`** file in your module? & before that did you created any module? Please provide the appropriate location of the above coded files

Comment: I know how to create custom modules, i am just asking, how to implement Ajax Pagination.

Comment: @KamranKhan Have you got solution for Ajax Pagination I am looking for same ?
Please share your solution so it is helpful for create custom Ajax Pagination.

Comment: Please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358190/82670

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName**

**registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_data" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Custom Data">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="25" comment="Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="email" nullable="false" length="25" comment="Email"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="description" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Descrition"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="custom" frontName="custom">
            <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**CustomData.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData as CustomDataResourceModel;

class CustomData extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(CustomDataResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel**

**CustomData.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class CustomData extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custom_data', 'id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/CustomData**

**Collection.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData as CustomDataModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData as CustomDataResourceModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomDataModel::class,
            CustomDataResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Index**

**Index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Custom Pagination'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**custom_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
     <head>
        <script src="VendoreName_ModuleName::js/ajax_pagination.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Pager" name="custom.ajax.pagination" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::pager.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block**

**Pager.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Pager extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData
     */
    protected $customFactory;

    /**
     * @var \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $customdataCollection;

    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData $customFactory
     * @param \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData\CollectionFactory $customdataCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData $customFactory,
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData\CollectionFactory $customdataCollection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->customFactory = $customFactory;
        $this->customdataCollection = $customdataCollection;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Custom Pagination'));
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $page_size = $this->getPagerCount();
        $page_data = $this->getCustomData();
        if ($this->getCustomData()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\CustomPager::class,
                'custom.pager'
            )
                ->setAvailableLimit($page_size)
                ->setShowPerPage(true)
                ->setCollection($page_data);
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getCustomData()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pager HTML
     *
     * @return \VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\CustomPager
     */
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    /**
     * Get custom data collection
     *
     * @return \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData
     */
    public function getCustomData()
    {
        $page = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
        $pageSize = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 5;
        $collection = $this->customFactory->getCollection();
        $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $collection->setCurPage($page);
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Get custom data collection
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPagerCount()
    {
        $minimum_show = 5; // set minimum records
        $page_array = [];
        $list_data = $this->customdataCollection->create();
        $list_count = ceil(count($list_data->getData()));
        $show_count = $minimum_show + 1;
        if (count($list_data->getData()) >= $show_count) {
            $list_count = $list_count / $minimum_show;
            $page_nu = $total = $minimum_show;
            $page_array[$minimum_show] = $minimum_show;
            for ($x = 0; $x <= $list_count; $x++) {
                $total = $total + $page_nu;
                $page_array[$total] = $total;
            }
        } else {
            $page_array[$minimum_show] = $minimum_show;
            $minimum_show = $minimum_show + $minimum_show;
            $page_array[$minimum_show] = $minimum_show;
        }
        return $page_array;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**pager.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
?>
<?php $custom_data = $block->getCustomData();?>
<?php if(!$block->getData('ajax_data')): ?>
<div class="custom-ajax-data">
<?php endif; ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <?php if(count($custom_data)): ?>
            <div class="table-wrapper custom-data ">
                <table class="data table table-data-items ">
                    <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml('Custom Pagination') ?></caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="col name"><?= $block->escapeHtml('Name') ?></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col orders"><?= $block->escapeHtml('Email') ?></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col orderitem"><?= $block->escapeHtml('Description') ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($custom_data as $item): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-th="Name" class="col name">
                             <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getName()) ?></span>
                            </td>
                            <td data-th="Orders" class="col orders">
                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getEmail()) ?></span>
                            </td>
                            <td data-th="Items" class="col orderitem">
                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getDescription()) ?></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
                    <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom">
                        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
                    </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="message info empty">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml('You have no data in table.') ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php if(!$block->getData('ajax_data')): ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block**

**CustomPager.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

class CustomPager extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager
{
    /**
     * Current template name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'VendoreName_ModuleName::html/custompager.phtml';

    /**
     * Return page limit params
     *
     * @param int $limit
     * @return array
     */
    private function getPageLimitParams(int $limit): array
    {
        $data = [$this->getLimitVarName() => $limit];

        $currentPage = $this->getCurrentPage();
        $availableCount = (int) ceil($this->getTotalNum() / $limit);
        if ($currentPage !== 1 && $availableCount < $currentPage) {
            $data = array_merge($data, [$this->getPageVarName() => $availableCount === 1 ? null : $availableCount]);
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve page URL by defined parameters
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPagerUrl($params = [])
    {
        $urlParams = [];
        $urlParams['_current'] = true;
        $urlParams['_escape'] = true;
        $urlParams['_fragment'] = $this->getFragment();
        $urlParams['_query'] = $params;

        return $this->getUrl($this->getPath(), $urlParams);
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getPath()
    {
        return "custom/index/ajaxdata";
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/html**

**custompager.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

/**
 * Pager template
 *
 * @see \VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\CustomPager
 */
?>
<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>

    <?php if ($block->getUseContainer()): ?>
    <div class="pager">
    <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($block->getShowAmounts()): ?>
        <p class="toolbar-amount">
            <span class="toolbar-number">
            <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(
                    __('Items %1 to %2 of %3 total', $block->getFirstNum(), $block->getLastNum(), $block->getTotalNum())
                ) ?>
            <?php elseif ($block->getTotalNum() == 1): ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('%1 Item', $block->getTotalNum())) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('%1 Item(s)', $block->getTotalNum())) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        </p>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
        <div class="pages">
            <strong class="label pages-label" id="paging-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></strong>
            <ul class="items pages-items" aria-labelledby="paging-label">
            <?php if (!$block->isFirstPage()): ?>
                <li class="item pages-item-previous">
                    <?php $text = $block->getAnchorTextForPrevious() ? $block->getAnchorTextForPrevious() : '';?>
                    <a class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($text ? 'link ' : 'action ') ?> previous ajax-page"
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPreviousPageUrl()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($text ? $text : __('Previous')) ?>">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($text ? $text : __('Previous')) ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowFirst()): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="page first ajax-page" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFirstPageUrl()) ?>">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                        <span>1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowPreviousJump()): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="page previous jump ajax-page"
                       title=""
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPreviousJumpUrl()) ?>">
                        <span>...</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php foreach ($block->getFramePages() as $_page): ?>
                <?php if ($block->isPageCurrent($_page)): ?>
                    <li class="item current">
                        <strong class="page">
                            <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You\'re currently reading page')) ?></span>
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_page) ?></span>
                        </strong>
                    </li>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <li class="item">
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPageUrl($_page)) ?>" class="ajax-page">
                            <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_page) ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif;?>
            <?php endforeach;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowNextJump()): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="page next jump ajax-page" title="" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getNextJumpUrl()) ?>">
                        <span>...</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowLast()): ?>
              <li class="item">
                  <a class="page last ajax-page" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getLastPageUrl()) ?>">
                      <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                      <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLastPageNum()) ?></span>
                  </a>
              </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if (!$block->isLastPage()): ?>
                <li class="item pages-item-next">
                    <?php $text = $block->getAnchorTextForNext() ? $block->getAnchorTextForNext() : '';?>
                    <a class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $text ? 'link ' : 'action ' ?> next ajax-page"
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getNextPageUrl()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($text ? $text : __('Next')) ?>">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($text ? $text : __('Next')) ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($block->isShowPerPage()): ?>
        <div class="limiter">
            <strong class="limiter-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Show')) ?></strong>
            <?php /*<select id="limiter" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"event":"change"}}' class="limiter-options"> */ ?>
            <select id="limiter" class="limiter-options ajax-limiter-options">
                <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getLimitUrl($_key)) ?>"
                        <?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                        selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_limit) ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <span class="limiter-text"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('per page')) ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($block->getUseContainer()): ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Index**

**AjaxData.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class AjaxData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(\VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Pager::class)
            ->setData('ajax_data', true)
            ->setTemplate("VendoreName_ModuleName::pager.phtml");
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $data = ['content' => $block->toHtml()];
        $resultJson->setData($data);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js**

**ajax_pagination.js**

```
require(
    ["jquery"],
    function($){
    $(document).on('click', 'a.ajax-page', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            type: 'POST',
            showLoader: true,
            success: function(response){
                $('.custom-ajax-data').html(response.content);
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).on('change', 'select.limiter-options.ajax-limiter-options', function(event){
        $.ajax({
            url: this.value,
            type: 'POST',
            showLoader: true,
            success: function(response){
                $('.custom-ajax-data').html(response.content);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

**[Click Here to Download](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HBdP5ml1C-JvDJ3l1g0Kz8WTB5CAx6vm?usp=sharing)**

***I Hope This Helps You.***